# Minimum of two integer-valued random variables

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have two integer-valued random variables $N_1,N_2$ and they satisfy $P(N_i\geq n)>0$ for any $n\geq 1$ and $i=1,2$. Will it be true that $P(\min(N_1,N_2)\geq n)>0$ for any $n\geq 1$?

Comment: Not necessarily.  For example, it is easy to make $\min (N_1,N_2)=0$.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The reason is that $\mathbb P(\min(N_1,N_2)\ge n)=\mathbb P(N_1\ge n,N_2\ge n)=\mathbb P((N_1,N_2)\ge(n,n))$ is determined by the joint distribution $(N_1,N_2)$, not by the marginals $N_1$ and $N_2$.

With this observation it is not hard to construct a counterexample. The idea is to force $N_2$ to be zero whenever $N_1$ is positive and vice versa. For example, consider the joint distribution $(B,N_1,N_2)$ given as follows. Let $B$ be Bernoulli with probability $1/2$. On $B=0$ let $N_2=0$ and let $N_1$ be Poisson with parameter $1$ (or any other distribution with infinite support in $\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$). On $B=1$ let $N_1=0$ and let $N_2$ be Poisson with parameter $1$. Then we have $\mathbb P(\min(N_1,N_2)=0)=1$, further $\mathbb P(N_1\ge n)=0.5\mathbb P(N_1\ge n|B=0)=0.5\mathbb P(\mathrm{Po}(1)\ge n)>0$ for $n>0$ and analogously $\mathbb P(N_2\ge n)>0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $N_1,N_2$ are independent, then
$$P(\min(N_1,N_2)\geq n)=P(N_1\geq n,N_2 \geq n)=P(N_1\geq n)P(N_2\geq n)>0\quad \forall n\geq1$$
If $N_1,N_2$ are not independent, then as pointed out by @Matija, $P(\min(N_1,N_2)\geq n)$ will depend on their joint probability distribution and the statement is not necessarily true.

Comment: Thanks! But actually $N_1, N_2$ won't be independent. And I think in that case we may not have the probability larger than 0.

Comment: Then it depends on their relationship.